Does the Ising model allow for quantitative predictions?
I was reading about the Ising model in a statistical mechanics book and then on Wikipedia and I understand that it is an interesting model as it allows one to make qualitative predictions about physical phenomena, e.g. the existence of a phase transition (in dimension $d \geq 2$) as observed with ferromagnetism.
There seems to be a lot of mathematical developments with advanced results (for different values of $d$), however, from the physical point of view, it is not clear to me how good the Ising model is to make quantitative predictions on real systems (e.g. about ferromagnetism or whatever system it can model).
My question is: can we use the Ising model to make quantitative predictions validated by physical experiments? (e.g. does it predict the value of the Curie temperature for some materials?)

It was never intended to. But one can design systems that are rather close to it.

Temperature no but it predicts critical exponents. Are you familiar with universality?

What @ConnorBehan says. And since this Ising model has many interpretations, it leads to critical exponents for (some class of) ferromagnets, fluids, binary mixtures, etc. They are often pretty close to those of the corresponding real systems. That being said, this is not why the Ising model is studied.

@ConnorBehan I wasn't, but this is enlightening.

@YvanVelenik "this is not why the Ising model is studied" <- why are they studied then?

Because it is a very simple model that allows a detailed mathematical analysis, while being at the same time rich enough that it can describe qualitatively a huge number of relevant physical phenomena. It also plays a central role as a laboratory in which one can test various approaches that can then later be applied to other more realistic models. The quantitative predictions, when available, are a bonus, but are certainly not the reason so many people study this model (in its various incarnations).
